# Access an object value using a key in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object like this one (simplified version):

```
var currentDepartment = 'development';

var departments = {
    "development":{
        "name":"Development",
        "number":"100"
    },
    "marketing":{
        "name":"Marketing",
        "number":"101"
    }
}
```

I know that if I want to access to the number I have to so something like `var number = departments.development.number` or `var number = departments.marketing.number`. But what if I can't hardcode the department name?

Something like, I should not write `development` or `marketing` directly, instead, I need to get the number of the department with the code in the variable `currentDeparment`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I apreciate it. =D

Comment: just complementing the @JJJ comment, maybe you want to check before if the key is in the object using `departments.hasOwnProperty("marketing")`